# How can I strip or replace a non-breaking space with Twig?

Tags: templating, currency

Using Twig, is it possible to strip out or replace a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`)?

I've got a string variable `price` (returned from the [`currency`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#currency) filter) that prints like this:

```
Nkr&nbsp;100,00
```

What I'd like, is to strip the `Nkr&nbsp;` part, so the string looks like this:

```
100,00
```

However, `{{ price|replace('Nkr&nbsp;', '') }}` does nothing, as the `replace` filter doesn't appear to actually match the non-breaking space.

`{{ price|replace({'Nkr' : ''}) }}` strips out the `Nkr` part, but leaves the `&nbsp;`; and I'm unable to remove it.

Here's what I tried already (after stripping the `Nkr` part):

```
{{ price|replace({'&nbsp;' : ''}) }}
{{ price|raw|replace({'&nbsp;' : ''}) }}
{{ price|striptags }}
{{ price|raw|striptags }}
{{ price|trim }}
{{ price|raw|trim }}
{{ price|replace({ '\u00a0' : '' }) }}
{{- price -}} 
{% spaceless %}{{ price }}{% endspaceless %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just think it is `&nbsp;` that get's returned from the filter, because that's how your developer tools display it, but in fact it is a *UTF-8 encoded* non-breaking space character. Have a look at the source code that is output and you won't see the `&nbsp;`.

The filter gets the formatting pattern from the [app/framework/i18n/data/no.php](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/framework/i18n/data/no.php#L32) file. Everything in this file is UTF-8 encoded and the non-breaking space is no exception.

So how can we remove it? Copy-and-pasting doesn't always work, because it depends on the apps used. On Mac OS X 10.11 I was able to simply copy the string from the source code view in the Safari dev tools to Atom editor and it worked. I can also generate the character with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Copying the snippet into this answer doesn't work though, it somehow converts it to a normal space:

```
{{ price|replace('Nkr ') }}
```

**Important sidenote:**

Mac OS X users who are like me and sometimes accidentially enter a non-breaking space character into their source code and then go mad trying to fix the error, have a look at this Apple Stack Exchange post: [What's alt+spacebar character and how to disable it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34672/whats-altspacebar-character-and-how-to-disable-it)

Atom editor users can install the [highlight-nbsp](https://atom.io/packages/highlight-nbsp) package.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a different spin... Try removing everything that's **not numeric or comma**.

```
{{ price|replace('/[^0-9,]/', '') }}
```

Comment: Ah, that's clever – works like a charm in this specific instance, thanks! However I'd still like to know how to strip out the `&nbsp;` in cases where a greedy regex like that wouldn't work (i.e. when I don't have a numeric string to deal with...)

Answer (score 3):

To add space between two words use below code:

```
{{ price|replace({" ": "&nbsp;"})|raw  |nl2br }}
```

This will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to trim a non-breaking space which is the UTF-8 encoded non-breaking space character:

```
{{ value|trim(" \t\n\r\0\x0B\xC2\xA0") }}
```

This works because internally Twig uses the PHP `trim`, `ltrim`, and `rtrim functions`.